# Open DVD Menu with VLC from command line

Tags: dvd, vlc-media-player

For some DVDs, VLC opens track 1 when I open a DVD. I prefer to open the menu. Is there a way from the command line that I can have VLC open the DVD menu? Currently I have to open it and then right click and go to Playback > Title > DVD Menu.

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass the name of the folder or drive, e.g.

```
vlc dvd://d:
```

See the command line reference manual for more details: https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Command_line/#Opening_a_DVD_or_VCD.2C_or_an_audio_CD

Comment: This for me is not equivalent to opening, right-clicking and going to playback > title > DVD Menu. Any way to do the equivalent of that right-click and playback > title > DVD menu from the command line?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to create a script that would determine the drive the DVD was in, if there was a drive, and if there were to many drives tell the user that it can't figure out what drive to do. This is what I came up with:

```
#Begin Script

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms


function Get-CDDrives {
@(Get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk -filter 'DriveType=5' |
ForEach-Object { $_.DeviceID })
}


$Drive = Get-CDDrives
if ($Drive.count -gt 1) {[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Unfortunately, you have more than one DVD drive, and I'm not smart enough to know which one to use for you video." , "Error" , 0)}
if ($Drive.count -eq 1) {& "C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" dvd:///"$Drive"\}
if ($Drive.count -lt 1) {[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Hmmm... I can't seem to find a DVD drive on your computer." , "Error" , 0)}
#End Script
```

Obviously, change the path to the VLC EXE if you need to. Here are the pictures of some of errors:
[image: More than one drive.]

[image: If No drives are detected.]